# Rails 3.1. Cocoon link_to_add_association example needed

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-3, cocoon-gem

pls show any example of using Cocoon's 'link_to_add_association' with html_options.
https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

Documentation says:

```
html_options: extra html-options (see link_to) There are two extra options that allow to conrol the placement of the new link-data:

    data-association-insertion-node : the jquery selector of the node
    data-association-insertion-position : insert the new data before or after the given node.
```

But i can not understand what to do, if i want insert partial just before my "add element" link. Not just after parent's div begin. This not gonna work:

> <%= link_to_add_association "add element", f, :production_years,
>   :position => "after_all" %>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I will admit that is a bit obscure, and maybe I should provide an example in the code.

In your `application.js` you should write something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.add_fields").
      data("association-insertion-position", 'before').
      data("association-insertion-node", 'this');
});
```

where `a.add_fields` will select your clickable link. I have only recently updated the readme with a better explanation how the insertion can be handled.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I thought it was well-documented  https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon#control-the-insertion-behaviour (or at least better than before).

Answer (score 6):

If you want to do it using data-attributes you can do:

```
<%= link_to_add_association 'Add Item', f, :items, :data => {"association-insertion-method" => "before" } %>
```

Comment: If you use `:data =>` You can not use jquery functions to get the association-insertion-node. Such as 
      `data("association-insertion-node", function(link){
        return link.closest('.row').next('.row').find('.sub_tasks_form')
      });`